# Как нарисовать звезду в круге c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Как на c# нарисовать звезду в круге используя picturebox?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    private void OnPaint()
    {
        int n = 5;               // число вершин
        double R = 25, r = 50;   // радиусы
        double alpha = 0;        // поворот
        double x0 = 60, y0 = 60; // центр
        Graphics e = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        PointF[] points = new PointF[2 * n + 1];
        double a = alpha, da = Math.PI / n, l;
        for (int k = 0; k < 2 * n + 1; k++)
        {
            l = k % 2 == 0 ? r : R;
            points[k] = new PointF((float)(x0 + l * Math.Cos(a)), (float)(y0 + l * Math.Sin(a)));
            a += da;
        }

        e.DrawLines(Pens.Black, points);
        e.DrawEllipse(Pens.Green, 60, 60, 200, 200);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnPaint();
    }
}
```

}

У меня получилось только вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сначала нарисовать круг, а потом нарисовать линии. С чем конкретно у тебя возникают проблемы? Что конкретно пытался сделать? На чем застопорился?

Comment: и какая связь рисования с функциональным программированием?

Comment: @Andrew , вот что получилось https://imgur.com/a/EyoYore

Comment: Щит Капитана Америки?

Answer (score 3):

Вы вызываете `DrawEllipse()`, передавая вторым и третьим аргументом координаты центра:

```
double x0 = 60, y0 = 60;
            ^^       ^^
// ...
e.DrawEllipse(Pens.Green, 60, 60, 200, 200);
                          ^^  ^^
```

Однако согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawellipse#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawEllipse_System_Drawing_Pen_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_) функция ожидает там координаты верхнего левого угла:

```
public void DrawEllipse (System.Drawing.Pen pen, int x, int y, int width, int height);
                                                     ^      ^
```

Можно, конечно, просто поправить числа. Но лучше вообще от них отказаться, динамически подгоняя круг под звезду:

```
e.DrawEllipse(Pens.Green, x0 - R, y0 - R, R * 2, R * 2)
```

Comment: вот что получилось https://imgur.com/a/sPNqufP

Comment: Попробуйте `e.DrawEllipse(Pens.Green, x0 - R, y0 - R, R * 2, R * 2)`

Comment: У меня просто нет C#-варианта Visual Studio.